# Create a 2 level json Array using Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need to contruct a Json with 2 parts first of all I need to obtain a name of companies from an ApiRest it returns a Json with the name of the companies and a parameter that contains an address for each company that have de members of the company. The Json that I need to construct is something like this:`

```
[
  {name: Company1,
   members:
     { member1: 
         {
           name: albert,
           age: 16
          },
        member2:
          {
            name:joan,
            age:18
          }
     }
  },
  {name: Company2,
   members:
     { member1: 
         {
           name: albert,
           age: 16
          },
        member2:
          {
            name:joan,
            age:18
          }
     }
  }
]
```

The firts api rest is http://api1.getcompanyies and return :

```
 [{
   "_links": {
     "url": {
         "href": "http://api.company.members/1"
     }
   },
   "name": "Company1",
  }, 
  {
     "_links": {
        "url": {
          "href": "http://api.company.members/2"
        }
     },
     "name": "Company2",
  }, {
     "_links": {
         "url": {
            "href": "http://api.company.members/3"
         }
     },
     "name": "Company3"}
```

The second api Rest Response is:

```
{"employes": [
    {
       "name": "Mickael Ciani",
       "age": "16"
     },
     {
        "name": "Albert dd",
         "age": "18"
     }
]}
```

first I tried to do with nested $http but don't works:

```
$http(firstApi)
    .then(function(res) {
            $scope.ob = {};
            angular.forEach(res.data.teams, function(value, key) {
                var companyName = value.name;
                $scope.ob[companyName] = {};
                $scope.ob[companyName].memberUrl =  alue._links.url.href;
                $scope.teams2.push(value.name);
                $http(paramsPlayers)
                   .then(function(res2) {
                        // construct the array
                    },
                    function() {}
                     );
                });
            return $scope;
        },
        function() {}
    );
```

Then i tried to do without nested http but still don't work because the contruction of first object is incorrect , i think

```
$http(firstApi)
    .then(function(res) {
            $scope.ob = {};
            angular.forEach(res.data.teams, function(value, key) {
                var companyName = value.name;
                $scope.ob[companyName] = {};
                $scope.ob[companyName].memberUrl =  alue._links.url.href;
                $scope.teams2.push(value.name);
                });
            return $scope;
        },
        function() {}
    );
 $http(2apiparams)
    .then(function(res2) {
           //construct final json
        },
        function() {}
    );
```

Thank You For all

Comment: Is this what you want ? `$q.all({ companies: $http(firstApi), teams: $http(secondApi)).then(function(response){
 var merged = [];
 response.teams.forEach(function(company){
  merged.push({
   name: company.name,
   members: response.teams.employes
  });
 });
 return merged;
})` inject $q. Your data example seems weird - very different with what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$q.all` for this scenario. I have written a angular service named `CompanyService` and a test implementation for the same. Hope this helps. You can use this service in your application. Take a look at [promise chaining](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-promise-chaining-explained) to get more idea on the implementation

```js
var testData = {
  companies: [{
    "_links": {
      "url": {
        "href": "http://api.company.members/1"
      }
    },
    "name": "Company1"
  }, {
    "_links": {
      "url": {
        "href": "http://api.company.members/2"
      }
    },
    "name": "Company2"
  }, {
    "_links": {
      "url": {
        "href": "http://api.company.members/3"
      }
    },
    "name": "Company3"
  }],
  memebers: {
    "employes": [{
        "name": "Mickael Ciani",
        "age": "16"
      },
      {
        "name": "Albert dd",
        "age": "18"
      }
    ]
  }
};
angular.module('app', [])
  .factory('CompanyService', function($http, $q) {
    var COMPANY_API = 'your company api url';
    var service = {};
    service.getCompanies = function() {
      //comment this for real implementation
      return $q.when(testData.companies);
      //uncomment this for real api
      //return $http.get(COMPANY_API);
    };

    service.getMemebers = function(url) {
      //comment this for real implementation
      return $q.when(testData.memebers);
      //uncomment this for real api
      //return $http.get(url);
    };

    service.getAll = function() {
      return service.getCompanies()
        .then(function(companies) {
          var promises = companies.map(function(company) {
            return service.getMemebers(company._links.url.href);
          });

          return $q.all(promises)
            .then(function(members) {
              return companies.map(function(c, i) {
                return {
                  name: c.name,
                  members: members[i].employes
                };
              });
            });
        });
    };
    
    return service;
  })
  .controller('SampleCtrl', function($scope, CompanyService) {
    $scope.companies = [];
    CompanyService.getAll()
      .then(function(companies) {
        $scope.companies = companies;
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
  <pre>{{ companies | json }}</pre>
</div>
```